# docker process hangs on write system call to stdout

Tags: linux, docker, tty, pty

One application process inside a docker was not responding. When we strace'd the pid, process was stuck in the following line.

**Strace Ouput:**

```
root@hostname-blah ~ # strace -p 29353
strace: Process 29353 attached
write(1, "\n", 1
```

file descriptor 1 was pointing to /dev/pts/0

```
echo "abc" > /dev/pts/0
```

also got stuck in this affected docker container (but it was working in other containers).

Answer (score 2):

This could be caused by this issue in Docker, that is specific to containers with allocated TTY: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35865